# The plot has the problem of lines getting collided with each other and not having proper formatting

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbpt!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis=true,
            width=0.7\textwidth,
            height=0.4\textwidth,
            xlabel={\textbf{Duration [Minutes]}},
            ylabel={\textbf{Temperature [$^{\circ}$C]}},
            xmin=0, xmax=750,
            ymin=0 , ymax=2500,
            xtick={ 10, 35, 215, 335, 695},
            ytick={},
            legend pos=north west,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            nodes near coords = {\pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}}}
            ]
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=square,
            ]
            coordinates {(0,0)(35,1419)(215,1431)(335,1430)(695,1400)
            };
            \addlegendentry {Trial  5}
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=square,
            ]
            coordinates {(0,0)(30,1400)(197,1448)(200,1440)(270,1400)(380,1401)
            };
            \addlegendentry {Trial  6}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Activity and temperature profile for trial 5 and trial 6}
    \label{Temperature Profile}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not compileable....

Answer (score 0):

I did following things to solve your problem:

1. I reduced the font size of your labels with `nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}`
2. With `nodes near coords align={above}` in the optinal arguments in the `addplot` you can seperate the labels.
3. One label still overlaps because they are too close together. I therfore, I made another `addplot` with only the one mark and shift it with `nodes near coords align={yshift=10pt}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbpt!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis=true,
            width=0.7\textwidth,
            height=0.4\textwidth,
            xlabel={\textbf{Duration [Minutes]}},
            ylabel={\textbf{Temperature [$^{\circ}$C]}},
            xmin=0, xmax=750,
            ymin=0 , ymax=2500,
            xtick={ 10, 35, 215, 335, 695},
            ytick={},
            legend pos=north west,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
            nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
            nodes near coords = {\pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}}}
            ]
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=square,
            nodes near coords align={below},
            ]
            coordinates {(0,0)(35,1419)(215,1431)(335,1430)(695,1400)
            };
            \addlegendentry {Trial  5}
            \addplot[
            nodes near coords align={above},
            color=black,
            mark=square,
            ]
            coordinates {(0,0)(30,1400)(200,1440)(270,1400)(380,1401)
            };
            \addlegendentry {Trial  6}
            \addplot[
            nodes near coords align={yshift=10pt},
            color=black,
            mark=square,
            ]
            coordinates {(197,1448)
            };      
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Activity and temperature profile for trial 5 and trial 6}
    \label{Temperature Profile}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @roland for the help

Comment: Can you please let me know that how can i add comments between two node points. The reason is, i want to show the activity performed during this time. It would be a great help.

Comment: @divyeshk, and how you imagine, that this text will be readable? You my consider to draw you diagram with `xmin=1350` and `ymax=1450` and increase image height. After than maybe be enough space for what you like to do!